# How to generate Quiver Graph and Equilibria Graph?

Tags: r, differential-equations

I have used Python in the past but have been slowly transitioning into R. I am currently trying to create a quiver/direction field graph and equilibrium graph. I have been able to do this in Python, links to examples below, but have had difficulty mirroring this in R. In Python I was able to use packages such as numpy, matplotlib.pyplot, mpl_toolkits.mplot3d, and scipy.integrate. Currently, I have been trying to use deSolve, pracma, and matlab. Are there other packages I should be using, or are the functions in these packages and I am unable to get them to work? An example of code from a paper I have been messing around with is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t) and model equations
Example <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {

    dK <-  a * K - b * H - c * F - d * H * F
    dH <-  b * H - a * K + c * F + e * F
    dF <-  f + c * F - a * K + b * H + h * K
    list(c(dK, dH, dF))
  })
}

#Parameters and Initial Conditions
parameters <- c(a = 0.02, 
                b = 0.01, 
                c = 0.04, 
                d = 0.06, 
                e = 0.08, 
                f = 0.2,  
                h = 0.04)
state      <- c(K = 0.7, 
                H = 0.6, 
                F = 0.3) 
times      <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.01) 

out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = Example, parms = parameters)

plot(out)
```

Here are the links to graphs I am attempting to mirror as much as possible:

[Equilibrium Graph](https://i.imgur.com/twEXvyP.png?1)

[image]

[Quiver/Direction Field Graph](https://i.imgur.com/pcJzdRH.png?1)

[image]

Comment: Once we sort out the errors, now we have 6 series: y1,....,y6. Exactly what are we supposed to be doing with these?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I apologize, I edited it to a 3-dimension model to simplify it some more. 

I was wondering, with this as a random example, how would I generate Equilibrium and Quiver graphs similar to the examples I have above from Python? 

I do not know which packages are capable of this. I have deSolve, matplot, and phaser but could not find functions for these options. I was hoping someone could either guide me in the right direction (i.e., what packages), or if they have the time, give me an example? 

Is ggplot2 capable of producing graphs for differential equations?

Comment: ggplot2 doesn't yet do 3d graphs as far as I know. The rgl package does suer rotatable 3d graphics and the lattice package and base package both have pseudo3d functions that allow fixed viewpoint displays. The author of deSolve also wrote a plot3d package that does fixed viewpoint graphics. I still get an error with your current code because R would not allow the code inside the function to "see` those lettered variable names inside `parms`. I've seen 3d vector fields and parametric 3d curve plotted and even done some on my own. Will do some searching.

Comment: Thanks, this was already helpful. Do you know if the plot3d package he wrote is integrated in deSolve already, or if I need to download it separately?

I apologize for that example not working. I am editing the post with a new one that I just ran and works well. Again, thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: It's not integrated in the sense that it gets installed or is a dependency when deSolve is installed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and see if I can find it. It should e easy if I look up wht writer of deSolve and what packages he has created in the cran database, I think.

Comment: I think Karline is a woman.

Comment: Actually looking at the name, I believe you are correct. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

With you current example I don't see a way to make a vector field but I do get something like the example you show of the equilibrium plot. I would have called it a 3d-parametric plot with time as the parameter.  An X11 window opens and you can rotate it in psuedo-3d sapce by click-dragging the image on your screen. The rgl.snapshot takes a picture. I decided to scale the axes:

```
require(rgl)
 open3d()
#------
NSOpenGL 
      11 
> lines3d( x=out[, 2]/diff(range(out[, 2])),  y=out[, 3]/diff(range(out[, 3])), z=out[, 4]/diff(range(out[, 4])))
> axes3d()
> range(out[, 2])
[1] -599.9068  309.3532
> range(out[, 1])
[1]   0 100
> range(out[, 4])
[1] -18.02914  23.64377
> range(out[, 3])
[1]   0.6000 165.0494
> rgl.snapshot("equil.png")
```

## [image]

There's also the scatterplot3d package:

```
require(scatterplot3d); scatterplot3d( out[, 2],  out[, 3], out[, 4])
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to use your code to produce an equilibrium plot from my old model (i.e., the one used in my pictures) and it mimicked it exactly. I will try to read up on the packages information of that function so that I can add labels and more.

How were you able to upload the rgl snapshot onto this website? Did you use imgur, or is there another method?

I found the plot3d you talked about. Their pacakge works through rgl. I will mess around with that to attempt a vector graph. Thank very much!

Comment: Do you think there are any pros or cons between using rgl or scatterplot3d?

Comment: I have been able to complete the graph using the scatterplot3d and want to thank you for your help, it is extremely appreciated.

The scatterplot3d worked well and I was able to use it for the project, but I am now trying to work with the rgl and openplot example you provided, just for personal interest. Looking at the reference manual for rgl and open3d I can't figure out how to modify or edit much of the model. For example, if I wanted to add label names to the x-, y-, and z-axes, how would I implement this into the code?

Comment: I (might) already have a (highly voted) answer to that one. Just look up my user postings on `scatter3d`. It applies to scatter3d which creates an rgl object, but might apply to ordinary rgl as well. If not, then post a complete question.